# How to calculate z-score using mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I want to find z-score normalization using **mongodB**.

I have a data with various fields. For example :

```
{id:1,speed:20},
{id:2,speed:30},
{id,speed:40}
```

I want to find z-score by looping through all the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation pipeline has a [`$stdDevPop`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/stdDevPop/) operator that you can use to calculate the standard deviation for your population:

`db.test.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "1", stdDev: {$stdDevPop: '$speed'}}}])`

Once you have that, you can run another aggregation to calculate the z-scores:

```
db.test.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    "id": 1,
    zScore: {$divide: ['$speed', standardDeviationYouCalculated] }
}]
```

If you wanted to accomplish this in a single command, [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) should allow you to "join" back to the original collection.